# Is the Arduino ground or the common ground the same as Earth ground? Why or why not?

Tags: arduino, ground, grounding

Is the Arduino ground or the common ground the same as Earth ground? Why or why not?

Is the Arduino ground or the common ground the same as Earth ground? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes or no. Because different applications have different requirements.

Answer (score 6):

> Q1. Is the Arduino ground or the common ground the same as Earth ground? Why or why not?

Not unless the Arduino ground is connected to Earth ground. In the case of battery powered equipment there is usually no connection between the two. Similarly any isolated mains supplied devices won't have a ground - Earth connection.

> Q2. Is the Arduino ground or the common ground the same as Earth ground? Why or why not?

Not unless the Arduino ground is connected to Earth ground. In the case of battery powered equipment there is usually no connection between the two. Similarly any isolated mains supplied devices won't have a ground - Earth connection.

Comment: +1 for the repeat.

Comment: and why not answer the title too?

Answer (score 1):

Ground just means a 0V reference point, but can be floating.

Earth ground means that reference is also connected to earth and thus is a safety 0 V ref